# Android Activity onCreate

Tags: android, oncreate

I add a recycleView (MainActivity) to my application. When I touch an item an activity (ItemActivity) is called having some info about the item + an action button. I have a method that populates the recycleView within `onCreate` (MainActivity) method.

I have installed it on two cellphones, one with Android 5.1 and the second with Android 4.2.

On 5.1, I choose an item, execute the action with the action button and back to the list (mainAcitivity) using the "Back Button". The `onCreate` method is called, thus, the recycleView is updated.

On 4.2, I do the same thing but when I go back the `onCreate` method is not called.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

The bottom line it, I need to reload the recycleView after the action.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Not right know, I'm at home, the code is at work.

Answer (score 1):

onCreate is called only when activity is created or was destroed. If you navigate back activity can still exist and your should use onStart to catch this. Or onResume.

Look here for activity lifecycle:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: But this difference between Android 5 and 4, why one call onCreate when I go back and the other doesn't? I don't finish the first activity, I open the second "above" it.

Comment: I first case activity is still exist in memory (perhaps there is more memory on device), when you came back onResume is called. I second case activity is destroed and when you came back it is recreated and onCreate is called. Look on activity lifecycle on link I gave you.

Comment: @Notheros It has nothing to do with `Android` OS version. It's a matter of memory on a device.

Comment: I understand. Thanks Alekz.

Answer (score 0):

Override Activity's onResume() method, call method to load recycleView in onResume.

Comment: Also, it's probably more correct to use
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
instead of the whole initialize